# Multiple if statements not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is not a duplicate.

I'm trying to do the following, perhaps there's a better way:

If value A is less than 1, round up.
Example, if value is 0.88, round to 1. This was easy:

```
var A = 0.88
if(a < 1 ) {
var A = Math.round(a);
document.getElementById("value").value = A;
}
```

But i also need the following:

Value A should be rounded to 15 min increments. For example, if value A is 1 hour and 3 minutes, it should round to 1.15

If value A is 1 hour and 18 minutes, it should round to 1.30.

I tried this:

```
        diff = document.getElementById('test').value;

        if(diff < 1 ){
            var diff = Math.round(diff);
            document.getElementById("hours").value = diff;
        }else if(diff > 1 && diff < 1.24){
            var diff = 1.25;
            document.getElementById("hours").value = diff;
        }else if(diff > 1.25 && diff < 1.49){
            var diff = 1.50;
            document.getElementById("hours").value = diff;
        } else {

        }
```

But its not working...

Comment: What isn't working about it?

Comment: You shouldn't use `if` at all, just use arithmetic.